# Why does the get request not reach the view?

Tags: python, django, forms

I take the redirect request from the hidden input get tag, but it does not reach, I sat in the debug for an hour and looked at the code, tried to fix something, but everything seems to be correct, please help!

```
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserLoginForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            auth.login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f"{username}, Вы вошли в аккаунт")
            if request.GET.get('next', None):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next'))

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:index'))
else:
    form = UserLoginForm()

context = {
    "title": "Home - Авторизация",
    "form": form
}
return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)


 <form action="{% url "users:profile" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% if request.GET.next %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value={{ request.GET.next }}>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 text-center">
                            {% if user.image %}
                            <img src="{{ user.image.url }}"
                            alt="Аватар пользователя" class="img-fluid rounded-circle"
                            style="max-width: 200px;">
                            {% else %}
                            <img src="{% static "deps/images/baseavatar.jpg" %}"
                            alt="Аватар пользователя" class="img-fluid rounded-circle"
                            style="max-width: 150px;">
                            {% endif %}
                            <input type="file" class="form-control mt-3" id="id_image"
                                name="image"
                                accept="image/*">
                            {% if form.image.errors %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">{{ form.image.errors }}</div>
                            {% endif %}
```

form

request
<WSGIRequest: POST '/user/login/'>
user
<User: wicki>
username
'wicki'

Here is a link with a get request that should redirect to the profile after sending the post request http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/?next=/user/profile/

Comment: In`<form action="{% url "users:profile" %}"` you are using double quotes *within* double quotes.  Try changing to `<form action="{% url 'users:profile' %}"`

Comment: @raphael That doesn’t matter, the template tags are processed by the template, and it doesn’t care about the HTML quotes.

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be with how you're passing the next parameter in your form submission and how you're accessing it in your view. Let's make sure we're passing it correctly and accessing it properly in the view.

First, let's update your form to ensure that the next parameter is passed correctly:

```
<form action="{% url 'users:profile' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if request.GET.next %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">
{% endif %}
<!-- Your other form fields -->
```

> Alter function code this line

```
if user:
            auth.login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f"{username}, Вы вошли в аккаунт")
            next_url = request.POST.get('next')  # Get the 'next' parameter from the POST request
            if next_url:
                return redirect(next_url)
            return redirect('main:index')
```

Comment: it wasn't helped me